# Rider auto-insert braces like Java

Tags: c#, rider, braces

I'm a real Java guy so C# isn't far from my comfort zone, but what really is is the way Rider auto-completes my curly braces. In java I've always learned the convention to be the following:

```
public void thisIsAnExample() {
}
```

Rider, however, inserts braces like this:

```
public void thisIsAnotherExample()
{
}
```

What setting should I change for this? I already dug through the Jetbrains Rider documentation but it doesn't seem to say what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_CSHARP_BracesPageSchema.html

Comment: $0.02 => don't do that. I would suggest you instead embrace the naming and style conventions of the language you're using. Unless you're developing in a vacuum, your code will end up being harder to read for the typical C# developer. I use many languages and respect and conform to them with minimal effort or pain.

Comment: Yeah. It's not a matter of Rider: _every_ single C# code you'll ever read will have braces like Rider does. If you need to use C#, start learning to read it. The alternative is your code will always look wrong to everyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I suggest you embrace the C# style for C#, as it will help you differentiate between C# and java/javascript, the way to manage these types of behaviors universally between IDEs is with [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/)

> @RetiredNinja posted a direct reference to [the Rider EditorConfig docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_CSHARP_BracesPageSchema.html)
>
> ```
>  # Java style braces on the same line
>  [resharper_]csharp_brace_style = end_of_line
>  [resharper_]csharp_type_declaration_braces = end_of_line
>  [resharper_]csharp_empty_block_style = together_same_line
>  [resharper_]type_declaration_braces = end_of_line
>  [resharper_]brace_style = end_of_line
>  [resharper_]empty_block_style = together_same_line
> ```

If you choose not to use the *EditorConfig* file, then you can edit the Rider IDE settings directly

> Settings Menu > Editor > Code Style > C#

The power of EditorConfig is two-fold:

1. You can define global default code styles for your workstation across all languages that you use, in all IDEs.
2. You can define Solution/Project/Folder level defaults within your code and check that file into your source code repository to keep the style in sync for all members of your team, you can set this to override any local workstation or IDE settings and this will prevent the needless code diffs caused by different style rules.